# getting an opcode? To perform jmp

Tags: assembly, x86-64, machine-code, instruction-encoding

I specify:
E9 00 89 9F E8 90
But actually the transition to another address, I found a formula, but I don't understand how it works.
"FROM - TO - 5 bytes.
Let's say the OT is 0057A3FF.
And BC is 00899FE8.
Then: 0057A3FF - 00899FE8 = 31FBE9.
How do I subtract 5 bytes?
I tried to do it as follows:
31FBE9 - E9, since the jmp instruction is only 5 bytes.
But it still jumps to the wrong place.
I'm just starting to learn assembler, please ask someone to explain to me how to count correctly.

"described in the problem"

P.s. Platform: WINDOWS 7 ULTIMATE x64 bit

Comment: Which platform?

Comment: Windows 7 X64  ULTIMATE bit

Comment: Then its DEST - SRC - 5.

Comment: @tkausl  I don't understand all the abbreviations yet, could you tell me or send me a link what DEST and SRC mean. And did I understand correctly that 5 is 0xE9?

Comment: Destination address and source address. No, 5 is not 0xE9, 5 is 5.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just stumped by the number 5. I just don't understand how I can represent 5 bytes. For example:
"Hex code is 5" and that's it?

Comment: `I just don't understand how I can represent 5 bytes.` What? Your jmp instruction is 5 bytes long, thats why you have to subtract 5, the jump is relative to the address __after__ the jump instruction. You could also just calculate DEST - (address after the jump), would be the same result. `For example: "Hex code is 5" and that's it?` Again, what? 5 is a number. Just subtract that number from the other number.

Comment: @tkausl I meant, 5 in this formula is a hex number?

Comment: 5 in decimal and in hex are the same thing.

Comment: @tkausl Right, I'm just used to hexadecimal numbers usually being prefixed with 0x . 00899FE8 - 0057A3D0 - 5 = 31FC13 I wrote it down as follows: E9 31 FC 13 , but this shows that the jump would be to the wrong address

Comment: Its `E913FC3100`.

Comment: @tkausl Sorry. I forgot that you have to read from right to left. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `E9` is the opcode, followed by a 32-bit little-endian displacement.  It jumps by doing `RIP += rel32`, relative to the *end* of the jump instruction.  Since it's 5 bytes long, you subtract 5 if you're calculating relative to the start of the jump instead of the end.